Can't install any packages stuck over here
What's going wrong over here?
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: listiva@0.1.0
npm error Found: date-fns@4.1.0
npm error node_modules/date-fns
npm error   date-fns@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer date-fns@"^2.28.0 || ^3.0.0" from react-day-picker@8.10.1
npm error node_modules/react-day-picker
npm error   react-day-picker@"8.10.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\\Users\\mukhi\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2024-12-09T05_35_36_426Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\mukhi\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2024-12-09T05_35_36_426Z-debug-0.log


Yes, it's a bs ecosystem designed to make you loss time, and even if it work, it won't next year.

You have to add more details to the question. Add things like what you were trying to achieve and then post the error. It give clear idea for people to understand your question and then answer.

The simplest way is to bypass strict dependency checks using the --legacy-peer-deps flag:
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

This reverts to the dependency resolution strategy used in npm v6, ignoring peer dependency conflicts. While this works, it may lead to runtime issues if dependencies are truly incompatible.
Use --force (Not Recommended)
You can force npm to ignore dependency conflicts by using the --force flag:
npm install --force

However, this approach may result in a broken or unstable project, as the incompatible versions are forcibly installed.
